# Compiling Tensorflow with Bazel

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, bazel

I tried compiling tensorflow 1.3 from the HEAD of the master branch using the following line of shell command after running ./configure

```
sudo bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k --verbose_failures //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the following error in the end.

```
At global scope:cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build 
INFO: Elapsed time: 3834.785s, Critical Path: 196.95s FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

These were the warnings it gave initially.

```
WARNING: /home/pranav/tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1634:1: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../external/nsync/public' resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its package 'tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/pranav/tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:911:30
WARNING: /home/pranav/tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
WARNING: /home/pranav/tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (208 packages loaded).
```

Then loads of INFO. I'm not sure if it is of any help.

Bazel Version:

```
Build label: 0.5.4
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Aug 25 10:00:00 2017 (1503655200)
Build timestamp: 1503655200
Build timestamp as int: 1503655200
```

I read in some answer to run the following code,

```
$ bazel query --output=build 'somepath("//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen",  "//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json")'
```

And it gave me this.maybe this will be of help.

```
# /home/pranav/tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1546:1
genrule(
  name = "version_info_gen",
  generator_name = "version_info_gen",
  generator_function = "tf_version_info_genrule",
  generator_location = "tensorflow/core/BUILD:1546",
  srcs = ["//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json", "//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/head", "//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/branch_ref"],
  tools = ["//tensorflow/tools/git:gen_git_source.py"],
  outs = ["//tensorflow/core:util/version_info.cc"],
  cmd = "$(location //tensorflow/tools/git:gen_git_source.py) --generate $(SRCS) \"$@\"",
  local = True,
)
```

Also, "the bazel command i wrote" > log.txt doesn't fill the text file with the terminal outputs.

If you guys want more information to help me. Suggest me a way to copy the terminal output to a text file so that i can upload it on github and give you the link.
I also used --explain to write all explanations to a file . I can upload that also if you want.
I also tried --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0 to reduce my memory allocation in case of memory issues. Still doesn't work.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you paste entire output of bazel after running `bazel build ... pip_package`? You only showed warning, I guess the actual error is above it.

Comment: What compiler and what version of it do you use?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what compiler you are asking about.
I have gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
and pip version 9.0.1

Comment: There was nothing termed as ERROR anywhere in the output. And the actual output is too large to post here. Suggest me a way to write it to a file.

Comment: "the bazel command you wrote" &> log.txt

Comment: I made it work. The issue was with trying to compile XLA JIT. For some reason it didn't compile and shutdown without showing any errors in my computer. Without that it works fine now. Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. How did you resolve this? During configuration I made sure to not compile with XLA JIT support.

Comment: Does it shutdown without any errors? Are you trying to compile anything more than the defaults given in tensorflow site?